# Can I hide the "All on My iPhone" option in iPhone's Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts, gmail

I'm using Gmail for Contacts, Notes, Calendar, and Mail sync.

Since I only have one account, most of these apps don't have the top level selection page which let's you choose which account to use. They always use my Gmail account, which is exactly what I want.

The one exception is Contacts, which allows me to tap "Groups", and then has an option "All on My iPhone". I want to disable this feature, so that I don't accidentally add contacts that aren't synced with Gmail. The Notes and Calendar apps do this perfectly... I can only add notes and appointments to my Gmail account, not to the phone itself.

I'm using Gmail's Exchange sync, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Unless you manually go to that "All on My iPhone" section and add a contact, contacts would be created by default on the account you're viewing, i.e. Gmail. Just keep the Contacts app viewing only the Gmail contact list and you should be fine.</s>

iOS5 now has a *Default Account* option under *Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Contacts (section)* (Credit to [Peter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/16617/peter-johnson) for the update)

Comment: I could be wrong, but this is not the case when someone calls you for the first time and you tap "Add new contact" in order to add them. I'm not sure if this changed in iOS4 but this always saves it to my phone rather than gmail's contacts.

Comment: There is an option on the "Mail, Contacts Calendars" page in the Settings app which lets you decide which address book to use as your default.